# SQLite Select single colum where two tables match

Tags: sqlite, select, where-clause

Hi want to get all entries of a single colum of one table where two colums of two tables match (like `join`).

So far I sucessfully extract all columns of both tables with the `where` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.AB_ID=table2.AB_ID
```

but when I only want to select a single column it is not working:

```
SELECT colX FROM table1 WHERE table1.AB_ID=table2.AB_ID
```

probably a rather simple problem...

Comment: You lack `table2` in the `FROM` clause of the second query. And if both tables have `colX`, you'll have to use `table1.colX`.

Comment: thank you... I missed the 'table2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a join:

```
SELECT table1.colX from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.AB_ID=table2.AB_ID;
```